# How do I download an MUI premium template

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is a free MUI premium template I want to use on my react project.

https://mui.com/store/items/onepirate/

I click on download and it takes me to the github page.

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/onepirate

I have tried cloning the repo but I am always hit with

> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/onepirate/' not found

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help please?